# Tortoise SVN problems commiting and updating

Tags: tortoisesvn

ok, i updated our website/web application with 1 file yesterday, and it popped up and error. It didnt really give me any specifics as to what the error was, but when i tried updating again. I got this: 
[image: error]

I cant update, i can't commit...The other programmer, is on the same account, and his works fine, on a different computer. Anyone know of how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried doing an SVN cleanup on your working copy?

Comment: "popped up an error" is pretty much meaningless. When you're dealing with your version control system, *any* error message is important enough to read and, if you're not sure, write down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the `Clean up` command from context menu:

[image]

You can also try deleting and then updating whole working directory

Comment: ok..like where it says mars..i have several folders..i can upload to others just fine...it's just mars, so delete whole folder then update the parent directory(websites), which would hopefully restore it? i know it wont let me update anything in mars or mars itself, thats why i ask....also ..what exactly does clean up do?

Comment: @EddyWhitaker: You should only delete the directory in which you have problem. Also clean up commands works in case of locks, did you try that ?

Comment: `svn help cleanup` will explain what it does. `svn help <anycommand>` will give you useful information.

Comment: i havent but i will right now..i also made a back up of the directory